# Local State not updating on Update of Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I have a component which gets it local state updated from redux state

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.updatePanelInTemplate = this.updatePanelInTemplate.bind(this);
        this.getPanels = this.getPanels.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            myCustomTemplate: this.props.myCustomTemplate
        }
        console.log(this.state);
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        resumeTemplate: state.resume.resumeTemplate,
        components: state.resume.components,
        myCustomTemplate: state.resume.myCustomTemplate
    }
}
```

These are my fraction of code involved. I am updating the redux state in a lifecycle hook `componentDidUpdate()`

My Redux is showing the changes all well.
I have put one console in each of them.
it prints in following order

```
console--mapState // empty state
console--constructor // empty state
console--mapState// full state after update
```

But my local state doesnot reflect any change after this update. I dont know why. Any more requirement pls do mention.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps`. Did you try with that life cycle hook>

Comment: do I have to update state there?

Comment: Yup. You should handle it in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.updatePanelInTemplate = this.updatePanelInTemplate.bind(this);
    this.getPanels = this.getPanels.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        myCustomTemplate: this.props.myCustomTemplate
    }
    console.log(this.state);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { myCustomTemplate } = nextProps;
    if (myCustomTemplate !== this.state.myCustomTemplate) {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            myCustomTemplate,
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state);
        })
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        resumeTemplate: state.resume.resumeTemplate,
        components: state.resume.components,
        myCustomTemplate: state.resume.myCustomTemplate
    }
}
```

Comment: But componentWillReceiveProps needs to start with a condition and compare nextprops to previous, otherwise it will set state at every update. Also in "myCustomTemplate, nextProps.myCustomTemplate", the comma should be a colon I think(?)